# Routing Multicast on a single L3 switch

Tags: multicast

I am currently testing how to route Multicast on a single L3 switch. I am currently testing 2 Vlans. I researched and I know I have to use PIM or Mrouter port for this scenario but that is for when you have a dedicated router. I can't wrap it on my head on how to do it on a L3 switch only. Any advice?

Two vlan interfaces where do I assign the mrouter port so they can pass multicast on each other?

Many Thanks,
6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi an welcome to network engineering.

The mrouter port is a concept from multicasting at L2 (in extenso: IGMP snooping). It does not pertain to multicast *routing* in the strict sense.

If you have a L3 switch that supports multicast routing (PIM), there is no need for an explicit mrouter port. The SVI ("interface vlan"), as soon as enabled for multicast routing, will process *IGMP Join* messages by end systems, and will also send out IGMP queries.

That being said, it is still a good idea to turn on IGMP snooping for the given VLANs, to ensure proper forwarding of multicast at the swichting layer - at the same time, IGMP snooping will detect the "internal switchport towards the SVI" as the mrouter port.

- enable multicast routing on the switch
- enable the relevant SVIs for PIM [1] along with the bits the selected PIM mode requires. [2]

**[ADD-ON1 - Answer to comments]**

> in my case I don't need the rendezvous point address? cause I only
>   have 1 layer 3 switch right?

If you choose PIM sparse mode, then (at least by principle) you need an RP and a way for particpating routers to learn about it (static, auto-rp, BSR). I must admit that I'd have to research deeper if that is also true if you only have a single mcast router.

That's also why I suggested starting with PIM dense mode - it does not require an RP, so the question and its complexities does not even come up.

> I just have to enable Igmp snooping and querier on both vlans and then
>   Ip multicast-routing and PIM sparse mode on the vlan interfaces?

Multicast routing, IGMP snooping, pim mode for interfaces: yes. IGMP querier: not necessarily. As soon as you there is an active multicast router in a subnet (actually: a router's PIM enabled interface, even if it's an SVI), this router will process IGMP, too, and will perform the IGMP queries - there is no need to define an IGMP Querier explicitely.

IGMP Querier (for IGMP Snooping) is an auxiliary construct for (V)LANs *without* multicast routers, to allow all igmp snooping switches to learn a (dummy) mrouter port and keep their multicast forwarding tables tidy (and not have to resort to flooding).

**[/ADD-ON1]**

---

[1] There's some Cisco catalyst switches with inter-vlan routing support that have "PIM stub" support: multicast forwarding between locally attached subnets, unable to form PIM adjacencies with other routers.

[2] the simpler dense mode might be good enough to start with.

Comment: Hi thank you Marc Appreciate the reply!

I am still getting familiar with Mrouter and PIM for Multicasting. in my case I don't need the rendezvous point address? cause I only have 1 layer 3 switch right? I just have to enable Igmp snooping and querier on both vlans and then Ip multicast-routing and PIM sparse mode on the vlan interfaces?